# in sqlite update trigger with multiple if/Case Conditions

Tags: sqlite, if-statement, triggers, switch-statement, case

In Trigger how to get multiple Condition check like

```
CREATE TRIGGER record_big_order AFTER INSERT ON orders 
BEGIN 
IF new.value > 1000000 THEN 
  INSERT INTO big_orders (customer_name, salesman_id, value,Mark) 
                  VALUES (new.customer_name, new.salesman_id, new.value,'1') 
END IF; 
IF new.value > 2000000 THEN 
  INSERT INTO big_orders (customer_name, salesman_id, value,Mark) 
                  VALUES (new.customer_name, new.salesman_id, new.value,'2') 
END IF; 
IF new.value > 3000000 THEN 
  INSERT INTO big_orders (customer_name, salesman_id, value,Mark) 
                  VALUES (new.customer_name, new.salesman_id, new.value,'3')
END IF; 
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below INSERT statement -

```
INSERT INTO big_orders (customer_name, salesman_id, value,Mark) 
VALUES (new.customer_name, new.salesman_id, new.value,
        CASE WHEN new.value > 3000000 THEN '3'
             WHEN new.value > 2000000 THEN '2'
             WHEN new.value > 1000000 THEN '1' END)
```