# Using CASE statement to INSERT values into multiple columns in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm trying to use INSERT statement to add values to a few columns in a new table depending on the value of a column in another table. I'm writing in SQLite. I was inspired by this question [in sqlite update trigger with multiple if/Case Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188107/in-sqlite-update-trigger-with-multiple-if-case-conditions) which used CASE statement in one of the columns, but I would like to apply to all the columns that I'm adding.

The code I have wrote is similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE machine_info (
    MachineType TEXT,
    MaxPower INTEGER,
    Frequency REAL);

INSERT INTO machine_info (MachineType, MaxPower, Frequency)
    VALUES (
    CASE WHEN parts.Machine = "A" THEN "Diode", 200, 60
         WHEN parts.Machine = "B" THEN "AC", 500, 50
         WHEN parts.Machine = "C" THEN NULL, 500, NULL 
    );
```

And the error message says `Result: near ",": syntax error`. Did I wrap the CASE statement at the wrong place?

Comment: This question has been edited. The original question looked I would fill in new columns to an existing table. In that case, using UPDATE as @forpas answered would be the right way to do it. Or copy the column "Machine" to the new table, UPDATE the table and drop the column, although SQLite doesn't support drop column at the moment.

Comment: Take some time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/10498828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, but you'll need `CASE` expressions for each of the 3 columns:

```
INSERT INTO machine_info (MachineType, MaxPower, Frequency)
SELECT
    CASE Machine WHEN 'A' THEN 'Diode' WHEN 'B' THEN 'AC' END,
    CASE Machine WHEN 'A' THEN 200 WHEN 'B' THEN 500 WHEN 'C' 500 END,
    CASE Machine WHEN 'A' THEN 60 WHEN 'B' THEN 50 END
FROM machine_info
WHERE Machine IN ('A', 'B', 'C');
```